# C++ - Qt + v8 under msvc2012

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, linker, v8

Recently, I've started a project under *Qt5.1.0*.
After some development, I choose to make a scripting system under *Javascript* with *Google V8*.
Under *Windows 7 x64*, the only way to compile *V8* is under *msvc2012*, and I got 3 .lib files to use.
In a single project **using ONLY V8**, everything works well. But integrating V8 with an existent project using Qt5 it's a bit more complicated.

Here is an example of a minimal code I'm using : (Of course, there is more file in this project...)

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;

int v8_test() {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  Handle<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);
  Persistent<Context> persistent_context(isolate, context);
  Context::Scope context_scope(context);
  Handle<String> source = String::New("'Hello' + ', World!'");
  Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
  Handle<Value> result = script->Run();
  persistent_context.Dispose();
  String::AsciiValue ascii(result);
  printf("%s\n", *ascii);
  return 0;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    std::cout<<"Starting application"<<std::endl;
    QApplication app(ac, av);

    v8_test();

    //Do something else

    return app.exec();
}
```

At this point, I got a lot of linking errors of this type :

```
1>v8_base.x64.lib(api.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in moc_aCertainFile.obj
1>v8_base.x64.lib(v8threads.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in moc_aCertainFile.obj
1>v8_base.x64.lib(checks.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in moc_aCertainFile.obj
```

It seems that Qt was compiled with `/MDd` flag, and V8 can only be compiled `/MTd` flag.

After lot of research and testing, I was unable to find anything...
Anyone got a clue to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are completely sure V8 can _only_ be compiled with `/MTd` (why would they do that?), then the only solution is to also compile Qt with that flag. No way araound afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was unable to use V8 and Qt5 in this way, even after many tries to build Qt in static.

So, I wrote a .dll wrapper for V8, which can be integrated into my project on QtCreator.

Here is my wrapper :

WrapTest.hh:

```
#ifndef WRAPTEST_HH_
#define WRAPTEST_HH_

#include <iostream>

namespace v8w {

    class WrapTest {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) void   hello();
    };
}

#endif /* WRAPTEST_HH_ */
```

WrapTest.cpp:

```
#include <v8.h>

#include "WrapTest.hh"

void    v8w::WrapTest::hello() {
    std::cout<<"Hello, i'm V8 wrapper! :D"<<std::endl;
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
    v8::Handle<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);
    v8::Persistent<v8::Context> persistent_context(isolate, context);
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
    v8::Handle<v8::String> source = v8::String::New("'Hello' + ', World!'");
    v8::Handle<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(source);
    v8::Handle<v8::Value> result = script->Run();
    persistent_context.Dispose();
    v8::String::AsciiValue ascii(result);
    printf("%s\n", *ascii);
    std::cout<<"End v8w::WrapTest::hello()"<<std::endl;
}
```

I've got **WrapTest.hh**, **V8_Wrapper.lib** and **V8_Wrapper.dll**, and a add the .lib to my .pro file into my Qt5 project :

```
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/lib"\
        -lV8_Wrapper
```

In my Qt project, the main.cpp file :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>

#include "WrapTest.hh"

void testV8() {
    std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
    v8w::WrapTest::hello();
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    std::cout<<"Starting application"<<std::endl;
    QApplication app(ac, av);   

    testV8();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Which gave me in the standard output :

```
Starting application
test
Hello, i'm V8 wrapper! :D
Hello, World!
End v8w::WrapTest::hello()
```

I hope this solution can help you if you're in the need ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Google V8 is built by default with `MT` flag and consequently incompatible with Qt which is build with `MD` flag.

The trick to get it to build V8 with Qt is to make the V8 compilation in visual studio with `MD` flag. You can do this with the following:

1. Generate the Visual Studio projects by executing build\gyp_v8.py.
2. Open all.sln with Visual Studio.
3. In all projects from the solution set the MD flag: properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library > Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)
4. After that rebuild the solution
5. You will get the correct lib files to use with QtCreator.

In QtCreator proceed with the linkage of V8 libraries:

```
LIBS += -L/PATH_TO_LIBRARIES/ -lv8_base.ia32 -licui18n -licuuc -lv8_nosnapshot.ia32 -lv8_snapshot
```

You need also to link with `WinMM.lib`, `WS2_32.lib` and `advapi32.lib`, they are normally found in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\

This made it on my system. I hope it helps other people with the same problem.

Comment: Are there any downsides to doing this?  I read that Google specifically chose /MT to reduce dependencies, but is changing it even significant enough that it might cause a problem?